# ROWNUM in CURSOR of oracle sql query is not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Please look at the below oracle function,

```
DROP FUNCTION get_mapper_requests;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_mapper_requests(p_status IN NUMBER, p_rownum IN NUMBER)
RETURN  SYS_REFCURSOR
AS

CUR_MED_MAPPER_STATUS SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

dbms_output.put_line('Status Value:'||p_status);

dbms_output.put_line('Row Count:'||p_rownum);

OPEN CUR_MED_MAPPER_STATUS FOR SELECT cmd_id,status FROM CDFDBA.MED_COM_MAPPER_CMDS WHERE 
STATUS=p_status and ROWNUM < p_rownum;

RETURN CUR_MED_MAPPER_STATUS;

END;
```

**The above function return all records even though if I pass any integer value to variable p_rownum. For ex if p_rownum=10, the function returns all records,**

Calling block

```
DECLARE

 c SYS_REFCURSOR;

 v  VARCHAR2(1000);

 v1 VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN

 dbms_output.put_line('Hello');

 c := get_mapper_requests(0, 10);

 LOOP

    FETCH c INTO v,v1; 

    dbms_output.put_line('Value from cursor: '||v||' '||v1);

 END LOOP;

 CLOSE c;

END;
/
```

Please support.

Answer (score 1):

After you `FETCH` in the calling code I think you're missing

```
EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
```

Without that I'd assume you code just keeps calling `DBMS_OUTPUT` with the last fetched row until you get an error for filling the dbms output buffer.

Comment: Awesome. It worked now. But here i assumed that cursor will have only 10 records when i pass the value as 10. Could you please elaborate me more about this situation?

Comment: The `LOOP` is not magically tied to the cursor. So you need to explicitly break our of the loop. Your cursor was fetching 9 rows (`<10`) but the loop kept going on for ever, with `v` and `v1` set to "undefined" (which I think means `NULL`). So that line we put in effectively means drop out of the loop when the fetch does not return anything (ie. the end of the cursor).

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
   cursor c is select * from <table_name> where rownum < 15;  -- SELECT ONLY 15 ROWS OF TABLE
   type t is table of c%rowtype index by pls_integer;
   tab t;
begin
   open c;
   loop
      fetch c bulk collect into tab limit 10;   -- FETCH cursor in chunks of 10
      dbms_output.put_line('X'); 
      exit when c%notfound;
   end loop;
end;
```